# Where is the error in this function to print a random array?

Tags: arrays, c, function

I don't understand where the error is in the function.I need to print 2 arrays with random elements.

```
int *boo3(int *x , int n){
        x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        x[i] = rand()%10-(rand()%10);;
        printf("%5d ",x[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int *x ,*y;
        int n , m;
        int i,j;
        printf("enter size of X[n]: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("enter size of Y[m]: ");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        x=boo3(*x,n);
        y=boo3(*y,m);
        free(x);
        free(y);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: just doing return x in the `boo3` function would work

Comment: Normally your compiler should tell you that there is no return value in `boo3`. If you didn't get that, you should turn up warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra` to achieve that.

Comment: If you're in a hurry, then please start **paying attention to the compiler diagnostic messages**!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code:

- `x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` overwrites the function parameter x.
- No return statement in boo3,
- `x=boo3(*x,m)` in this line, `*x` is dereferencing pointer `x` which gives you `int`
- In main function, you tried to free uninitialized pointer `x` and `y`

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
int *boo3(int *x , int n)
```

This indicates that you should receive a return value from this function.
In general a return value can be error code or any data which you might want to use going ahead.
Just like a math function for addition, taking operands as an argument and returning the sum. In your case, it is a pointer to the memory you have been allocated with.

In `boo3()` function, you are allocating some memory and you need the pointer to that memory for further usage. `boo3()` doesn't return anything, however, in `main()` function, you are assuming that you have caught it, hence the problem.

You should return the pointer to data from `boo3()`.

I can see in `main()` function,

```
x=boo3(*x,n);
```

This is alarming. You are dereferencing a `int*` pointer and passing an `int` (instead of `int*`) as an argument to `boo3()` function which expects a `int*`.

If you wish to assign the pointer declared in `main()` with the address of memory allocated in `boo3()`, then you don't catch it and change to

```
boo3(x, n);
boo3(y, m);
```

And change to

```
void boo3(int *x , int n)
```

However, ideally, the function should return and the value be caught as a return value. In that case, change to

```
int* boo3(int n)
```

At the end of `boo3` add a `return x;`. And use it as

```
x = boo3(n);
```

Additionally, you are not checking if the `malloc()` has allocated any memory or not. You should check if the pointer is NULL to see if memory is allocated. It is minimum error-checking and handling you need to have. Secondly, `malloc()` returns a `void*`, so the typecast is needless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you do not return anything from the function `boo3()`, and try to use the return value. This causes undefined behavior.

You need to add a `return x;` at the end of the function so as to return the pointer holding the address of the allocated memory (and populated values).

That said, passing the pointer argument is not needed when you return the pointer from the function. Apart from the fact that your call does not even try to pass a pointer as the first argument, as expected by the function signature - to allocate memory to a pointer from a called function, you need to pass the address of the pointer anyways, passing the pointer alone will not suffice. You don't need to do that, just define the function as

```
 int *boo3(int n) { //......
```

and in the end, add
return x;

and from `main()`, call it like

```
    x=boo3(n);
    y=boo3(m);
```

Comment: what value should I return for the program to work correctly?

Answer (score -1):

There are many issues in your code.

Following has been corrected:

- `boo3` now simply returns the pointer to the allocated memory filled with random numbers, the useless `x` parameter has been removed and the function now contains the missing `return` statement. This is actually the main problem in your code.
- The pointless `(int*)` cast has been removed from `malloc`.
- The code is formatted properly.
- Variables are declared as close as possible to their scope. This is the idiomatic way, declaring all variables at the start of the scope is a thing from the last century.
- Usage of meaningful variable names.

This is a correct version of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* boo3(int n) {
  int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = rand() % 10 - (rand() % 10);;
    printf("%5d ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return array;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sizex, sizey;
  printf("enter size of X[n]: ");
  scanf("%d", &sizex);
  printf("enter size of Y[m]: ");
  scanf("%d", &sizey);
  int *xvalues = boo3(sizex);
  int *yvalues = boo3(sizey);
  free(xvalues);
  free(yvalues);
  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: for brevity there is no error checking for `scanf` and `malloc`.

Comment: To set a good example, also ensure that `array` is not null before indexing into it, and use the return value from each of those `scanf()` calls.  With those changes, I might accept that it's "correct"...